# How to filter out data in a column using pandas DF

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I have a column that looks like this:

```
Temp
Temperature 1:33.1, Temperature 2:-50.0, Temperature 3:-50.0, Temperature 4:-50.0^
Temperature 1:26.7, Temperature 2:-50.0, Temperature 3:-50.0, Temperature 4:-50.0^
Temperature 1:31.1, Temperature 2:-50.0, Temperature 3:-50.0, Temperature 4:-50.0^
302,16/06/2021 15:28:49,0,0,0,0,0,0^
$36,515,0,1,1,00124F^
```

This data is sent by a tcp server app that I build, I have used a another python script to write the raw data to a text file, clear out the unwanted fields like:
`, Temperature 2:-50.0, Temperature 3:-50.0, Temperature 4:-50.0^`
and  `Temperature 1:` etc. and leave out only numbers, then I write the lines to an output file.txt and then convert it to a DataFrame, the df is pushed to an sql server every 60 seconds.
regardless to say that this code is not efficient, now i changed the code to read the text file directly to a DF, but now i'm struggling with the manipulation of the data.

here is a snippet from my code:

```
 # Create a custom list of values I want to cast to NaN, and explicitly
    # define the data types of columns

    df = pd.read_csv("c:/input.txt", error_bad_lines=False, sep="|", engine="python")
    df.columns = ['Plate_number', 'Date_Time', 'NA1', 'NA2', 'NA3', 'NA4', 'Temp']
    # manipulate the data that only floats are written in the temp column    
    df["Temp"]=df["Temp"].replace(to_replace=", Temperature 2:-50.0, Temperature 3:-50.0, 
    Temperature 4:-50.0^", value="0")
    s = df['Temp'].astype(str).str.findall("\-?\d+\.\d+")
    df['Temp'] = pd.to_numeric(s[s.str.len() == 1].str[0])
    # fill 0 anywhere that has a NaN
    # df = df.fillna(value=0)
```

If anyone can help, I'll be grateful.

Comment: so basically you just want the temperature values, and only if they are *not* `-50.0` (which I assume is your no-value-indicator?), correct? Those other temperature fields, do you plan on feeding those with valid data as well sometimes?

Comment: @MrFuppes, yes, i need only the Temp values, without the precdeing "Temperature 1:", all the other temperature fields are not needed because they are not used. please pay attention to spam that is coming every once in a while like:  ```302,16/06/2021 15:28:49,0,0,0,0,0,0^``` or  ``` $36,515,0,1,1,00124F^ ```

Comment: I understand you just need the number after `Temperature 1:` at the start of string. If there is none, keep NaN (or you may use some default value if needed). See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df=  pd.DataFrame({"Temp":["Temperature 1:33.1, Temperature 2:-50.0, Temperature 3:-50.0, Temperature 4:-50.0^",
"Temperature 1:26.7, Temperature 2:-50.0, Temperature 3:-50.0, Temperature 4:-50.0^",
"Temperature 1:31.1, Temperature 2:-50.0, Temperature 3:-50.0, Temperature 4:-50.0^",
"302,16/06/2021 15:28:49,0,0,0,0,0,0^",
"$36,515,0,1,1,00124F^"]})
>>> df['Temp'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Temp'].str.extract(r'^Temperature\s+1:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', expand=False))
>>> df
   Temp
0  33.1
1  26.7
2  31.1
3   NaN
4   NaN
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dLKVfW/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `Temperature` - a word
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `1:` - a `1:` string
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1: one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits.

Comment: FYI: if you need a zero as default value and not `NaN`, use `df['Temp'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Temp'].str.extract(r'^Temperature\s+1:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', expand=False).fillna(0))`

Answer (score 1):

I'd clean the data as I read it from the textfile.

Ex:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO # for demo only

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample data
s = """Temp
Temperature 1:33.1, Temperature 2:-50.0, Temperature 3:-50.0, Temperature 4:-50.0^
Temperature 1:26.7, Temperature 2:-50.0, Temperature 3:-50.0, Temperature 4:-50.0^
Temperature 1:31.1, Temperature 2:-50.0, Temperature 3:-50.0, Temperature 4:-50.0^
302,16/06/2021 15:28:49,0,0,0,0,0,0^
$36,515,0,1,1,00124F^"""

with StringIO(s) as f: # read the file to a list of strings
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

# to dict
data = defaultdict(list)
for line in lines:
    if 'Temperature' in line: # select only temperature data
        line = line.replace('^', '') # clean
        for element in line.split(', '): # split to individual temperature values
            k, v = element.split(':')
            data[k].append(float(v) if v != '-50.0' else np.nan)
                
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
#    Temperature 1  Temperature 2  Temperature 3  Temperature 4
# 0           33.1            NaN            NaN            NaN
# 1           26.7            NaN            NaN            NaN
# 2           31.1            NaN            NaN            NaN
```